# counting the number of instances of a particular class on stage in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, instance

Does some one know how to get the number of instances of a particular class (in my case Ball.as) currently on the stage.

Note: I want a solution to not include the use of numChildren and then looping through all children, as I want the number of Balls every enterFrame and looping like that might just make my code more heavier.

So any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static variable within the class to keep track,  but that you means you have to correctly keep track at this variable at all times, or it could end up with the wrong count.

```
public static var count:int = 0;


public Ball() {
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded);   
   addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, onRemoved);
}

private function onAdded(event:Event):void {
   removeEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAddeed);
   Ball.count++;
}

private function onRemoved(event:Event):void{
   removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, onRemoved);
   Ball.count--;
}
```

and then whenever you want to count them:

```
trace(Ball.count);
```

Comment: Ah, this is the best solution ever. I do indeed have a class Game.as for all static stuff, but never thought of this.
But how could it go wrong on the count?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad Sorry, I just meant that you have to correctly update the variable when adding and removing Balls - the code I posted should do that correctly since it listens for ADDED and REMOVED events.

Answer (score 2):

### a) Count them

```
var balls:uint = 0;
for(var i:uint=0,l:uint = numChildren; i<l;i++)
  if(getChildAt(i) is Ball) balls++;
```

### b) Keep track of them

```
var balls:uint = 0;

function addBall():DisplayObject {
   balls++;
   return addChild(new Ball());
}

function removeBall(ball:Ball):DisplayObject {
   balls--;
   return removeChild(ball);
}
```

### c) Isolate them

```
var ballContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(ballContainer);

...

ballContainer.addChild(new Ball());

var balls:uint = ballContainer.numChildren;
```

Comment: He specifically says he doesn't want the solution to involve looping through numChildren, so (a) is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be a way to get around doing the loop.

When I have an Actionscript project of any size I will create a static Manager class that will handle all app wide variables. You could create an Array in there and add/remove from that when a new instance of ball is created.